# Controls and null reference exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I'm aware that the `NullReferenceException` is pretty much the equivalent to the check engine light on a car but with this particular case I can't seem to pinpoint why its not working properly, I've never really messed with controls so I'm a bit unfamiliar in with the technicalities of it. What I have works, but I keep getting the exception when I run a `trycatch` around it. Here is what I have.

```
Dim TypeControl As Control

TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")

DBTable = MaterialStuff.GetMaterial(ID)

    Using DBTable

        If DBTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            Try
                  CType(TypeControl, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text = (DBTable.Rows(0).Item("MaterialTypeDescription").ToString)

Catch ex As NullReferenceException

                trace.runAllErrorLogging(ex.ToString)

            End Try

        End If
```

Comment: `"I'm aware that the NullReferenceException is pretty much the equivalent to the check engine light on a car"` - Your check engine light means that your car has no engine?

Comment: Is either `TypeControl` or `SelectedItem` equal to Nothing?

Comment: `TypeControl` or `DBTable` could be nothing as could the `cbo.SelectedItem`.  Just check: `If DbTable IsNot Nothing THen ....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible problems here:

1 - Does `FindControl` actually find the control you seek? Add a check in to make sure you are actually finding it:

```
Dim TypeControl As Control
TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")
If TypeControl Is Nothing Then Debug.Writeline("Could not find control")
```

2 - The `SelectedItem` of the control could also be `Nothing` so you may need to add a check here:

```
Dim ddl = CType(TypeControl, DropDownList)
If ddl.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then Debug.Writeline("Could not find selectedItem")
```

Comment: It was the `selectedItem` that was `Nothing`. Thank you, I would probably never have looked at that.

Answer (score 2):

A `NullReferenceException` doesn't have anything to do with "controls" specifically.  It's just an indication that your code assumes an object exists when at runtime it doesn't exist.  For example, if you do this:

```
TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")
CType(TypeControl, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text = ...
```

Then your code *assumes* that `TypeControl` has a value on the second line.  If it doesn't, trying to use `.SelectedItem` will fail because `TypeControl` is `null`.  So you're assuming that `.FindControl()` actually *found* something.  It doesn't make that guarantee implicitly.

Instead of making this assumption, you should verify:

```
TypeControl = MaterialHeader_Edit1.FindControl("cboType")
If TypeControl Is Not Nothing Then
    CType(TypeControl, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text = ...
End If
```

That way the code only executes if there's a value that it can use.  You can add an `Else` to handle the condition where no value is found.  (Display an error?  Log the error?  Silently continue?  It's up to you how the condition should be handled.)